# How to use eager loading for related models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following models:

- Appointment [ belongsTo Timeslot  |  belongsTo User ]
- Timeslot [ hasMany Appointment ]
- User [ hasOne Appointment  |  HasOne Details ]
- Details [ belongsTo User  ]

I am trying to eager load the Details data starting from the Appointment model ( Appointment has a user, which has a Details record) using the following query:

```
$apps = Appointment::with('timeslot')->with('user')->with('user.details')->get();
```

This throws the following error in Builder.php

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Why am I calling on a non-object here and why is my query not working?

EDIT:

This is the relation on my User model:

```
public function details() {
    dd($this->role_id);
    switch($this->role_id) {
        case 3:
            return $this->hasOne('App\CandidateDetails', 'user_id');
            break;
        case 2:
            return $this->hasOne('App\EmployerDetails', 'user_id');
            break;
    }

}
```

i'm aware that this would be better implemented using a pivot table, it's been a learning process. the dd() returns a null when called by my query, yet it works fine in other calls. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have **return** in all your relation methods. It seems that one of them is not returning a **Relation** definition.

You can't use $this in relation definitions - attributes of the model will be uninitiated when query is built, so $this->role_id will give null and no relation will be returned.

In order to make it work you should define 2 separate relations:

```
// User.php
public function candidateDetails() {
  return $this->hasOne('App\CandidateDetails', 'user_id');
}

public function cemployerDetails() {
  return $this->hasOne('App\EmployerDetails', 'user_id');
}

public function getDetailsAttribute() {
  switch($this->role_id) {
    case 3:
      return $this->candidateDetails;
    case 2:
      return $this->employerDetails;
  }
}

// ...and then...
$user = User::with('candidateDetails', 'employerDetails')->findOrFail($userId);
// depending on user's role you'll get either candidate or employer details here
$details = $user->details;
```

Comment: You can't use $this in relation definitions - attributes of the model will be uninitiated when query is built, so $this->role_id will give null and no relation will be returned

Comment: Then what would be the most elegant way to implement this? I have a User model that operates on a Users table. Each record _either_ has a relation to the Candidates or to the Employers table.

Comment: I'd define 2 separate relations, eager load both and define a getter that for given user would return either of the related fields, depending of the role.